# Laravel Spatie To Get User Role

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

**model file**

```
class BanUser extends Model
    {        
    public function user()
                {
                    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "user_id", "id");
                }   
        
         public static function getBanList()
                {
                  
                    $getlist = BanUser::with(['user'])
                                ->get()
                                ->toArray();
            
                    return $getlist;
                    
                }
    }
```

**//data**

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [created_at] => 2020-09-16T16:06:54.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2020-09-16T16:06:54.000000Z
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => hi
                            [email] => hi@gmail.com
                            [email_verified_at] => 
                            [created_at] => 2020-09-10T12:18:18.000000Z
                            [updated_at] => 2020-09-10T12:19:11.000000Z
                   
                        )

                )
```

The above code is to retrieve all the ban user list, but every user have attached one role with it, how can i join the role table in order to retrieve the role by every user? I used the laravel spatie permission. Anyone can help on this? :(

Comment: Can you show relationship between user and role model?

Comment: so ... `with('user.roles')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you can use this

```php
public function user()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "user_id", "id")->with('roles');
}
```

this `roles` is added by `laravel spatie` so you can use this

this is roles model https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Models/Role.php

all the available function which you can use
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Traits/HasRoles.php

---

**in another way**

```php
public static function getBanList()
{              
     $getlist = BanUser::with(['user.roles']) // it will get user as well as all the roles of that user
                           ->get()
                            ->toArray();
      return $getlist;                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could pluck the `id` and `name` like this

`$request->user()->roles()->pluck('name','id');`